# Adding multiple tables to cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I was wondering if there is a way to combine multiple tables into a single cell array without using the curly braces `{}` to do so.

The current way that I am doing this is as follows:

```
Name = {'A','B'};
val = [1;2];
Table1 = table(val,'RowNames',Name);

Name2 = {'A','B'};
val2 = [3;4];
Table2 = table(val2,'RowNames',Name2);

CombinedTable = {Table1,Table2};
```

I would like to be able to make a CombinedTable cell array that has an unknown number of tables/elements in it without using the curly braces. The overall goal would be to use a loop to add various tables to the CombinedTable cell array.

Comment: Why not just combine the tables rather than putting them in a cell array?

Comment: @Suever That is an option but it is not the point of the question I am asking.

Comment: Have you tried doing this in a loop? It's pretty trivial `CombinedTable{loopindex} = table`

Comment: @Rotem I don't want to convert each table to a cell array, I want to create a cell array of tables.

Comment: @Suever Thanks, I don't know why I didn't think of that before. Thanks.